# nvd3 y2axis with fixed 2 minute time intervals

Tags: javascript, d3.js, nvd3.js

I am looking for help to see how I might be able to have a fixed time range on the y2axis (on the right) in hours,minutes and seconds %H:%M:%S. I did search before posting but could not see any similar topics.

Presently, the y2axis is using the values from the data source and sorting them.

What I would like is to have fixed 2minute intervals - see below example:

```
00:30:00
00:28:00
00:26:00
00:24:00
00:22:00
00:20:00
00:18:00
00:16:00
00:14:00
00:12:00
00:10:00
00:08:00
00:06:00
00:04:00
00:02:00
00:00:00
```

Here is the current code for lineplusbarchart that i am working with: http://jsfiddle.net/wrcjp79o/5/